# If I buy a new ship, can I transfer my components to that new ship?

Tags: rebel-galaxy-outlaw

So, I have the garbage collector that you start the game.

I'm winning and buying a bunch of stuff for it so I can gain more money killing other ships and completing missions.

If I get enough money to buy a new ship, will I be able to move those parts to the new ship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, everything is moved from one ship to another.